# onclick form submit redirect gives no post result in safari

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a serie of php pages with forms where users should make some choices. Very basic.

```
<form action='/nextpage.php' method='post' name='main' >
<input name='var1' type='hidden' value='xyz' />
<input name='var2' type='hidden' value='abc' />
<input name='direction' type='submit' value='North' />
<input name='direction' type='submit' value='East' />
<input name='direction' type='submit' value='South' />
<input name='direction' type='submit' value='West' />
<input name='var3' type='submit' value='NoDirection' onClick=\"document.forms.main.action='/endpage.php'; document.forms.main.submit();\" />
</form>
```

After submitting this form with a direction it will go nicely to nextpage.php and I can read the `$_POST` for `var1`, `var2` and `direction` variables as expected. Like I said very basic.

But if submit this form with `NoDirection1` it submits to `endpage.php`. In Chroome, IE and FF `$_POST['var3']`  gives me NoDirection like it should...

But in Safari `$_POST['var3']` is empty also

```
if (isset($_POST['var3'])) echo $_POST['var3'];
else echo "Help";
```

echoes "Help" instead of "NoDirection" in Safari.

Any ideas?  `onclick` or `onClick` makes no difference. Also  `onClick=\"javascript:document.forms.` etc did not do the trick.

I found a workaround but I want to understand the difference between Safari and the other browsers.

Workaround: just add `var3` as a hidden variable and unset it in `nextpage.php` and it works fine

```
<input name='var3' type='hidden' value='NoDirection'>
```

**SOLVED** seems like a double submit or something Safari won't like. I removed the code below after the onclick. It works fine now. Best 3 days spend puzzling this year :-)

```
document.forms.main.submit();
```

Comment: Safari on Mobile devices or computer? I know that mobile devices don't use OnClick, I think they use something else.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer (not as an edit to the question) and mark it as accepted :)